# Swing: Update Graphics every millisecond?

Tags: java, swing, graphics

I created a little sketchpad program with basic GUI. I used the paintComponent method. I want to update the graphic being drawn every millisecond. That way, the user can see what they're about to draw before they release the mouse click.
For example, if I'm drawing a rectangle, I want to see the rectangle **while** I'm drawing it.
If you're confused as to what exactly I'm talking about, open MS Paint and click on the rectangle tool. Draw a rectangle. Notice how it updates continuously, as opposed to after you release the mouse.
I figured that there must be some way I can get it to update my graphics every millisecond. What is the best way to go about doing this? Sorry if this is an easy question, I'm new to Swing! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well you don't update every millisecond.

You use a `MouseMotionListener` and you update every time a `mouseDragged` event is generated to redraw the Rectangle.

Check out [Custom Painting Approaches](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/?s=custom+painting) for two approaches on how to do this.

The examples show how to draw multiple rectangles by either:

1. Adding Objects to a List and then repainting each object every time the component is repainted
2. Painting directly onto a BufferedImage and the just painting the BufferedImage.

Comment: Thank you so much!! I thought I was overthinking it. :)

Comment: @pmcg521, glad it helped. Don't forget to "accept" the answer by clicking on the check mark so people know the problem has been solved. Also don't forget to "accept" answers in your other questions.

Comment: Why did you ask this question? I just noticed I gave you this answer 2 weeks ago. If we can take the time to read and answer your question. Then you can take the time to read the answers we give you, including the information in the links we provide.

Comment: Obviously it wasn't the  same answer. I don't have time to read every single topic within every link that is sent to me. But thanks for answering my similar questions about Swing

Comment: @pmcg521, You asked a follow up question about painting multiple circles on the same panel. You were given a link to a working example showing how to do that. It also showed how to draw the circle as the mouse is being dragged. So the point is you didn't download the code and try it. `I don't have time` - I just had to spend time answering this question even though you already had the answer. Why do you think we have the time???  Why is your time more important than ours??? . What about the time spend by the other people who read the question??? How many peoples time to you plan to waste?

Comment: Good questions, now maybe I can answer them. I really don't want to argue with you because you clearly don't understand the question that I asked previously. And you didn't HAVE to answer any question. You can use your time however you want; I'm not holding a gun to your head. I'm just a student asking a question, don't overthink it. I hope this answers your questions. If you thought this was the best answer, don't forget to click the checkmark :)

Comment: `And you didn't HAVE to answer any question` - agreed, but when  people do answer questions you are expected. to read the answers and take the time to understand them. Your laziness not to read the answer is no excuse for reposting a question and wasting the time of others who read the question. Other people don't know the question has been previously answered and so will try to help. This is a waste or their time which good be spend answering other questions from somebody who really needs the help.